# Exclude two or more directories in bash for loop

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, pattern-matching

I am having a parent directory called **Stem** in that parent directory I am having around 20 sub-directories and 20 sub-directories names are ending with **_a**, and each sub-directory is having a file called **violations.txt**. In those 20 sub-directories, two sub-directories name are **Trans_a** and **shift_a**, I do not need to perform any script action on these two sub-directories.
I need to execute my script on only 18 sub-directories.

I tried the below code but not getting the exact output.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "These warning reports are based on this run directory:" ; pwd
echo " " ;
File="violatons.txt"
for d in *_a;
do
if ( "$d"=="Trans_a"||"shift_a" ); then
True
else
    Statement 
fi
done
```

Note : In some situations the sub-directories which we need to exclude in script may increase or decrease, it depends upon the situation.

Comment: The `if` condition is probably wrong. Try this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47584/in-a-bash-script-using-the-conditional-or-in-an-if-statement

Comment: @Kavitha : Paste your script into [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/). Also yur `if` does not make sense. `if ( foo )` runs the command `foo` in a child shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for f in !(Trans|shift)_a/violations.txt; do
    echo "$f"
    # do stuff
done
```

`!(pattern-list)` Matches anything except one of the given patterns.

Reference: https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching